# How to use a secondary Activity in a LiveWallpaper Engine

Tags: android, android-activity, live-wallpaper

I have a class activity that make a graphic animation (MainActivity) in an AnimatedView. Work great as an app, BUT...
I want to launch this activity inside a Live Wallpaper and use it like a Animated wallpaper.
Is possible?

I try this simple code but don't work:

```
public class LiveWallpaperService extends WallpaperService {

private class LiveWallpaperEngine extends Engine {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(".MainActivity");
    startActivity(myIntent);

}
}

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```